# Calculated column used in reporting services shows #Error

Tags: calculated-column, reporting-services

I am using the following formula in a calculated column to extract the month from the "ResolvedDate" column.

```
=""&MONTH(ResolvedDate)
```

It works well, but now I intend to use it in reporting services so that I can display a graph with it. After connecting my dataset to this list, when I press "run query" to show my data, I get  #Error on that column. Consequently I cannot use it to build my graph.

Any pointers on how to resolve this?

Comment: It's been a while, but I thought that calculated columns couldn't be used in RS and ultimately the same logic had to be rebuilt in the report.

Comment: And where exactly in reporting services do I create a calculated column? Is the sintax the same?

Comment: I mean you have to rebuild the logic as an expression, the syntax should be the same or very similar, It has been a while since I used RS/BIDS,

Answer (score 0):

May Can solve it by Try Catch on Reporting Code

### see this example

Public Shared Dim sPara1 As String= ""
Public Shared Dim sPara2 As String= ""

Public Function getPara1() As String

TRY
        sPara1=Report.Parameters!Machine_NO.Value(0)
  CATCH
        sPara1 = "Not Select"
  END TRY

```
     Return sPara1
```

End Function

Public Function getPara2() As String

TRY
        sPara2=Report.Parameters!Machine_NO.Value(1)
  CATCH
        sPara2 = "Not Select"
  END TRY

```
     Return sPara2
```

End Function

---

get Data by Expression
=Code.getPara2()